# One-word naming convention for "send immediately"

Tags: java, naming-conventions, send

I have a networking application that creates some custom messages and buffers them sequentially in a FIFO queue, until a `send()` method is called, whereupon all these messages are transmitted to their intended destination.

There is also a need for providing a method that allows "send immediately" functionality, i.e. transmission of a message (or a group of messages) without taking into account the queue, which remains intact, waiting for the send() method to be called.

The class exposes an API of several methods, all of which are single English words and I would like to keep this convention.

So, is there any suitable one-word replacement for, say, `sendNow()`?

Comment: You might find you get a better answer on english.stackexchange.com with the `single-word-requests` tag

Comment: dispatch? A one word naming convention seems a bit restrictive to be honest.

Comment: "What should I name my function?" is not really a suitable question for SO...

Comment: "xxx" vs "xxxNow" seems pretty standard and self explanatory, see for example `shutdown` vs `shutdownNow` of an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 10):

You know what? I would go for `enqueue()` or `buffer()` instead of `send()` because this is what the method is doing. Maybe even consider `later(Message)`?

Then use `send()` for sending immediately.

Comment: There is another method already for putting messages in the queue, so send() actually does what you describe. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Transmit

A thesaurus may help you.

http://thesaurus.com/browse/Send?s=t

Answer (score 1):

Following some real word scenario, I would call it priority() as in priority mail. https://www.usps.com/ship/priority-mail.htm?

Comment: It should be a verb and prioritize() does not seem a very accurate word.

Answer (score 1):

I would use either `expedite` or `dispatch`. Neither one is perfect, however. Expedite has only vague connotations of sending something, while dispatch doesn't have quite the immediacy and might be mistaken as a synonym for send. I personally prefer `expedite`.

Answer (score 0):

How about hasten()?

http://thesaurus.com/browse/hasten

"speed something; hurry"

Comment: Not bad; at least better to "urgent()" that we considered using. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could `post()` your messages.